# Is there any way to get max and min values while keeping all other columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

```
df_A <- tribble(
  ~id,       ~type,     ~min_price,  ~max_price,
  "1",        "X",          10,          40,
  "1",        "Y",          20,          50,
  "1",         NA,          15,          70,
  "2",        "X",          40,          90,
  "2",        "Y",          23,         100,
)
```

Now, I want to get the rows that show us min and max of "min_price" for each id and type. So I coded:

```
data_x <- df_A %>%
  group_by(id, type) %>%
  summarise(min_price_1 = min(min_price),
            min_price_2 = max(min_price))
```

But in this situation, I lose other columns. When I replace it with mutate, then it is more complicated.

What's the way to get it?

Comment: Why is it more complicated with `mutate`? It seems to be what you are looking for...? If you use `summarise` then you have to aggregate all columns you want to keep

Comment: Do you mean you have other columns besides min_price, max_price, id and type? Then you need to use summarise_at()

Comment: `summarise_at` still drops other columns. If the other columns aren't trivial (i.e. have more than one value for some `id` and `type` groups, then you have to specify how those columns are reduced in the `summarise` call. If they are trivial, add them to `group_by`.

Comment: Depends on what is your expected output. Can you show us that ?